# Not getting result from Google Place Autocomplete Address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api

I am implementing [Google Autocomplete Address](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=fr) script with my current project and I am trying to find places with my keywords from Google search but I am not getting that result. **I have no restriction for any country.**

I am not good with Google codes so don't understand so I am hoping that you will help me.

**My search keywords is (Which is not showing Google result):**

1. Technodream Training, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India
2. Zydus Cadila Healthcare Ltd., Changodar, Gujarat, India
3. Crop Production Services Inc

**My Autocomplete Address Script Code:**

### HTML:

```
<div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
</div>
<table id="address">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Street address</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input class="field" id="street_number"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
            <input class="field" id="route"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">City</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
            <input class="field" id="locality"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">State</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Zip code</td>
        <td class="wideField">
            <input class="field" id="postal_code"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Country</td>
        <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
            <input class="field" id="country"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Lat</td>
        <td class="slimField">
            <input type="text" class="field" id="latitude"></input>
        </td>
        <td class="label">Long</td>
        <td class="wideField">
            <input type="text" class="field" id="longitude"></input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Script Code:

```
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

$("#autocomplete").on('focus', function () {
    geolocate();
});

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
    // to geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['geocode']
    });
    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
    // populate the address fields in the form.
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        fillInAddress();
    });
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    document.getElementById("latitude").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}
// [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
            document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;

            autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
        });
    }

}

initialize();
// [END region_geolocation]
```

I am getting all search result in Google script: https://www.google.com/maps/place/ and here is my JSFiddle work: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/q8XS6/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your JSFiddle work* is actually my JSFiddle work, but let's not care about that! ;-)

You are requesting `types: ['geocode']` which, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions) returns *addresses*.

For businesses, you should use `types: ['establishment']` or you can simply remove that line and you will get all types of results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. You helped me in my previews question. So I have to use `establishment` as type. right? Is it possible to use both?

Comment: Yes, as I said, remove the line and it will get all types. Read the documentation. It's quite clear: *If nothing is specified, all types are returned. In general only a single type is allowed. The exception is that you can safely mix the 'geocode' and 'establishment' types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no types.*

Comment: Okay I will check and inform you :)

Comment: It will work. I tested it with the search examples you posted.

Comment: Again thanks for your guidance. It's working as I am expecting.

Comment: I have changed my code but still not getting postal code: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=delhi&types=&language=en&components=&sensor=false&key=XXXXXXXXXXX